# solaris performances on comparable Sun / Dell / HP boxes

Tags: performance, solaris, dell, hp, sun

I understand this might be a little vague, but has anyone conducted some study of the performances of Solaris OS running on comparable (same CPU / RAM) boxes made by Sun, Dell, and HP ?

we're all Sun / Solaris and considering other HW vendors. considering the historical link between the HW and the OS, we're curious...

any input welcome !

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're going to run into some hellish problems with the new sun licensing (given that you seem to need a support contract, and they don't seem to want to sell you one without hardware support). That said, we run Solaris on a few Dell boxes, and there doesn't appear to be any noticeable difference in performance over Sun x86 boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked but I thought that you might like to know that we switched a very large number of our Sun boxes out onto Solaris x86 on HP blades and saw enormous immediate benefits in terms of space, power/heat and performance. Specifically we moved a lot of weblogic applications from V210's to BL460c G1's and saw a seven-fold increase in throughput with no tuning. We've had no stability issues and I would imagine that the same would be true on IBM etc. hardware too.

Comment: Is that because you moved off Sun hardware, or because you moved to beefier boxes?

Comment: Bit of both, as a company we moved away from Sun yet ironically setup a wide reach ELA with Oracle (funny how things turn out eh!) - but also we saw really great benefits in moving from SPARC to x86 in terms of raw performance as well as Watt-per-transaction and price-per-transaction as we get great prices on HP blades. If also gave us the ability to more cheaply move to much bigger x86 boxes too.

Comment: The question is asking about comparable hardware, same CPU/RAM. You are describing old generation SPARC vs newer Intel.

Comment: @jlliagre "Not what you asked but I thought that you might like to know"